# High cost in evaluating loop variable increment

Tags: performance, loops, assembly

We have a scientific code in Fortran and we're doing some hotspot analysis with VTune. The biggest hotspot it identifies is an `END DO`. Digging into the assembly code, 1/4 of the time spent on `END DO` is in the `jle` command. The remaining 3/4 is in the `incq` command on the loop index variable.

The `END DO` line is broken into an `addq`, `incq`, a `cmpq` and a `jle` and I would expect the comparison operator to take the longest.

But what really baffles me is why the `incq` is taking so long. In this particular case, the loop is performed 12 times for a total time of 120 ms spent just on the `incq`. Why would it take so long to increment the index variable?

This is a bit of a mess, but here's the original loop where the initial numbers are the line numbers that correspond to the assembly code:

```
796            DO NS = 1, NSPECI
857               IF (Tguess(iter) < Tmid(ns)) THEN
858                  M = 1
859               ELSE
860                  M = 2
861               END IF
862
863               Cpp = thcoef(1,m,ns)
864               Hfp = thcoef(1,m,ns) * Tguess(iter)
865
866               a_nTn = thcoef(2,m,ns) * Tguess(iter)
867               Cpp = Cpp + a_nTn
868               Hfp = Hfp + R2I * a_nTn * Tguess(iter)
869
870               a_nTn = thcoef(3,m,ns) * T2
871               Cpp = Cpp + a_nTn
872               Hfp = Hfp + R3I * a_nTn * Tguess(iter)
873
874               a_nTn = thcoef(4,m,ns) * T3
875               Cpp = Cpp + a_nTn
876               Hfp = Hfp + R4I * a_nTn * Tguess(iter)
877
878               a_nTn = thcoef(5,m,ns) * T4
879               Cpp = Cpp + a_nTn
880               Hfp = Hfp + R5I * a_nTn * Tguess(iter) + thcoef(6,m,ns)
881
883               CVP = CPP - 1.0_wp
884               hf = hf + hfp * Rgk_Yk(ns)
885               Cv = Cv + Cvp * Rgk_Yk(ns)
886            END DO
```

and the generated assembly:

```
        movq      112(%rax), %rdx                               #863.22
        movq      104(%rax), %r15                               #863.22
        imulq     %r15, %rdx                                    #
        movq      88(%rax), %rsi                                #863.22
        movq      80(%rax), %rcx                                #863.22
        imulq     %rcx, %rsi                                    #
        movq      %r8, -176(%rbp)                               #
        movq      thermo_m_mp_thcoef_(%rip), %r8                #863.16
        movq      64+thermo_m_mp_tmid_(%rip), %r14              #857.20
        subq      %rdx, %r8                                     #
        shlq      $3, %r14                                      #
        subq      %rsi, %r8                                     #
        movq      %rdi, -392(%rbp)                              #
        negq      %r14                                          #
        movq      64+thermo_m_mp_thcoef_(%rip), %rdi            #863.16
        shlq      $3, %rdi                                      #
        subq      %rdi, %r8                                     #
        movq      %rcx, -248(%rbp)                              #863.22
        movq      %r8, -240(%rbp)                               #
        movsd     .L_2il0floatpacket.46(%rip), %xmm6            #868.32
        movsd     .L_2il0floatpacket.47(%rip), %xmm5            #872.32
        movsd     .L_2il0floatpacket.48(%rip), %xmm4            #876.32
        movsd     .L_2il0floatpacket.49(%rip), %xmm3            #880.32
        pushq     $1                                            #796.13
        popq      %rcx                                          #796.13
        movsd     -280(%rbp), %xmm8                             #
        movq      %r15, %rdx                                    #
        movsd     -208(%rbp), %xmm2                             #
        movsd     -264(%rbp), %xmm1                             #
        movsd     .L_2il0floatpacket.52(%rip), %xmm7            #
        movsd     .L_2il0floatpacket.46(%rip), %xmm6            #
        movsd     .L_2il0floatpacket.47(%rip), %xmm5            #
        movsd     .L_2il0floatpacket.48(%rip), %xmm4            #
        movsd     .L_2il0floatpacket.49(%rip), %xmm3            #
        testq     %r12, %r12                                    #796.13
        jle       ..B10.15      # Prob 2%                       #796.13
..B10.13:                       # Preds ..B10.25 ..B10.13
        movsd     (%r14,%rcx,8), %xmm10                         #857.35
        movaps    %xmm2, %xmm15                                 #864.16
        xorq      %rax, %rax                                    #863.16
        comisd    %xmm2, %xmm10                                 #863.16
        setbe     %al                                           #863.16
        incq      %rax                                          #863.16
        imulq     -248(%rbp), %rax                              #863.22
        addq      -240(%rbp), %rax                              #863.16
        movsd     16(%rax,%rdx), %xmm11                         #866.24
        mulsd     %xmm2, %xmm11                                 #866.16
        movsd     8(%rax,%rdx), %xmm10                          #863.16
        movsd     24(%rax,%rdx), %xmm12                         #870.24
        mulsd     %xmm10, %xmm15                                #864.16
        addsd     %xmm11, %xmm10                                #867.16
        mulsd     %xmm6, %xmm11                                 #868.32
        mulsd     -232(%rbp), %xmm12                            #870.16
        mulsd     %xmm2, %xmm11                                 #868.40
        addsd     %xmm12, %xmm10                                #871.16
        mulsd     %xmm5, %xmm12                                 #872.32
        addsd     %xmm11, %xmm15                                #868.16
        mulsd     %xmm2, %xmm12                                 #872.40
        movsd     32(%rax,%rdx), %xmm13                         #874.24
        addsd     %xmm12, %xmm15                                #872.16
        mulsd     %xmm1, %xmm13                                 #874.16
        movsd     40(%rax,%rdx), %xmm14                         #878.24
        addsd     %xmm13, %xmm10                                #875.16
        mulsd     %xmm4, %xmm13                                 #876.32
        mulsd     %xmm0, %xmm14                                 #878.16
        mulsd     %xmm2, %xmm13                                 #876.40
        addsd     %xmm14, %xmm10                                #879.16
        mulsd     %xmm3, %xmm14                                 #880.32
        addsd     %xmm13, %xmm15                                #876.16
        mulsd     %xmm2, %xmm14                                 #880.40
        subsd     %xmm7, %xmm10                                 #883.16
        mulsd     -8(%rbx,%rcx,8), %xmm10                       #885.30
        addsd     %xmm14, %xmm15                                #880.26
        addsd     48(%rax,%rdx), %xmm15                         #880.16
        addq      %r15, %rdx                                    #886.13
        addsd     %xmm10, %xmm9                                 #885.16
        mulsd     -8(%rbx,%rcx,8), %xmm15                       #884.30
        incq      %rcx                                          #886.13
        addsd     %xmm15, %xmm8                                 #884.16
        cmpq      %r12, %rcx                                    #886.13
        jle       ..B10.13      # Prob 82%                      #886.13
```

The instructions for the `END DO` in question are:

```
    addq      %r15, %rdx                                    #886.13
    incq      %rcx                                          #886.13
    cmpq      %r12, %rcx                                    #886.13
    jle       ..B10.13      # Prob 82%                      #886.13
```

In the profiling, virtually no time is spent on the `addq` and 75% of the time is spent on the `incq`.

Comment: `inc` is known to be slow due to partial flags update. You (or your compiler) should use `add` instead and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Jester Any tips on how to get the compiler to make that substitution? An example on any compiler would help, I could figure it out from there. But I've never come across a way to do that and I don't know how to hand-roll an assembly version of the Fortran `END DO`.

Comment: Is this on an x86 ? How many instructions are in the loop ? You mentioned 12 iterations in this incident.  Can you predict on paper the maximum number of times the loop will iterate ? Can you write your own ASM routine to interface with the existing code ?  Not sure if this helps, but if any of the answers are "yes" that could give us a place to start thinking.

Comment: @User.1 It's x86_64 and there are a lot of instructions in the loop. I'll have to go back and count but it's pretty long. The loop will iterate a fixed number of times, determined at run-time (it's looping over the number of chemical species in a flow, which is fixed for the length of the run). I could probably find a way to write an assembly routine.

Comment: The attribution of time to instructions is not very reliable. A problem with loops and small counts can be misprediction (causing a pipeline stall and refill) if the loop is not laid out properly by the compiler; jumps back are predicted to be taken by default, jumps forward are predicted 'not taken'. Small changes in the source code can make a huge difference sometimes.

Comment: Yes, please post a bit of actual assembly for us to get our teeth into.

Comment: @DarthGizka I've added the assembly and the source code for the loop itself. VTune identifies the `END DO` as the most expensive (by a large margin) of the entire subroutine, of which this loop is just part.

Comment: The loop tail (END DO) looks all right to me, prediction and all. There seems to no flag dependency for INC to mess up either. The time spent in the loop tail instructions should in any case be minuscule compared to stuff in the body of the loop. This may be a case of a tool misinterpreting the profiler data, by summing all the hit counts for all instructions that logically belong to END DO. As you can see, the counts are all very similar and depend only on the hittable 'surface', i.e. instruction count. I cannot see any correlation between instruction latency/throughput and those numbers.

Comment: Sorry, it's very late... Just realised that those are line numbers. Oops! The thing with a tool mis-interpreting/mis-reporting things is still worth looking into, I think.

Comment: As Jester said, INC has a read dependency on the flags register because it updates only some of them but not CF (the carry flag). This means it has to wait for its preceding instruction to finish so that it gets a value for CF. An ADD overwrites all flags and doesn't read, so it does not have this dependency. In this case the INC instruction has to wait until the result for the MULSD is retired, and that can take a while. However, I doubt that you can fix the compiler to use ADD instead of INC... What kind of compiler can handle x64 and SIMD yet includes decades-old mistakes like that?

Comment: @DarthGizka This is the Intel Fortran compiler, and a relatively new version at that (within the past year).

Comment: LOL. Post a defect report @ Intel? I haven't heard anything about newer CPUs being able to see through the false dependency, but my docs are a year old already.

Comment: "The INC and DEC instructions modify only a subset of the bits in the flag register. This creates a dependence on all previous writes of the flag register. This is especially problematic when these instructions are on the critical path because they are used to change an address for a load on which many other instructions
depend. Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 33. INC and DEC instructions should be replaced with ADD or SUB instructions, because ADD and SUB overwrite all flags, whereas INC and DEC do not, therefore creating false dependencies on earlier instructions that set the flags."

Comment: @DarthGizka If you put all your comments together into an answer, I'll give you a vote. Your analysis is a valid explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what's happening is that cycles are getting charged to the wrong instruction.  Profiling is often a bit inexact that way.  Or cycles get charged to the instruction that's stuck waiting to issue because the OOO engine's tracking resources are full.

Instructions have to retire in-order, so one old instruction that's stuck on something (e.g. a cache miss load or store) will eventually stall the pipeline when [the out-of-order window has gone as far beyond it as possible](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/).

I assume there's a long loop-carried dependency chain in the FP variables in that loop, since there are no stores, only loads.  And a (branchless) compare at the top which I assume depends on the result of the prev iteration.  So each iteration has to wait for the results of the previous one to execute.  But the loop-counter instructions aren't part of this dependency chain, so they can execute far ahead of the progress of the loop body.  (If there were any loads whose address depended only on the loop counter, they could get started far ahead of the code that used them).

So a lot of the time, the loop-overhead instructions will be the newest instructions that are completed, and they'll just be waiting to retire until over 100 uops of FP dependency chain clears out of the ROB (re-order-buffer).

I'm not sure if this is exactly correct, but I think it's a better guess than the `inc`-is-slow theory.  It's too bad the Intel manual misled everyone.

---

`inc` is *not* the problem, unless you're running this on a P4.  That section of the Intel manual is stale.  You only need to avoid `inc` in cases where you couldn't replace it with `add` (because you *do* need to preserve the carry flag, like an `adc` loop).

Even on P4, `inc` wouldn't be a problem for this code.  One false dependency isn't going to slow looping down so much that OOO execution can't see ahead into future iterations.  Also notice that there's an `inc %rax` early in the loop, and you didn't say anything about that being hot.

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki for optimization guides, including Agner Fog's excellent stuff.  If you want to know *why* `inc` is slow on P4, read his microarchitecture guide.

Answer (score 0):

As Jester has pointed out, the use of the INC is problematic because it does only a partial update of the flags register and thus it needs its previous value. This in turn means that it has to wait for the last flags-writing instruction to finish before it can execute. This can often slow down execution by introducing false dependencies.

In this particular case it forces an unnecessary wait for the result of a previous instruction in order to get a value for the carry flag (CF) which does not get updated by INC. If an ADD had been used then there would not have been a read dependency on the flags, since ADD only writes new values to all of them.

The previous flags-writing instruction in this case is the ADDQ %R15, %RDX on which the INC would not otherwise depend. It is hard to say why this dependency should have such a drastic effect here (it would have been more obvious with a long-running instruction like DIV or MUL; however, the SIMD instructions here like ADDSD and MULSD do not affect the flags).

The value of the carry flag is totally immaterial for the instructions following the INC since the CMPQ overwrite the flags without reading and the ADDSD doesn't care, which is why it is called a 'false' dependency.

Even the newest [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?wapkw=intel%C2%AE+64+and+ia-32+architectures+optimization+reference+manual) says:

> **3.5.1.1 Use of the INC and DEC Instructions**
>
> The INC and DEC instructions modify only a subset of the bits in the
>   flag register. This creates a dependence on all previous writes of the
>   flag register. This is especially problematic when these instructions
>   are on the critical path because they are used to change an address
>   for a load on which many other instructions depend.
>
> ***Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 33.*** (M impact, H generality) INC and
>   DEC instructions should be replaced with ADD or SUB instructions,
>   because ADD and SUB overwrite all flags, whereas INC and DEC do not,
>   therefore creating false dependencies on earlier instructions that set
>   the flags.

That's exactly what Jester said, and a professional compiler should certainly heed these coding rules.

Comment: This answer only applies to Pentium4.  Even if there was a false dependency on the flags, as you point out there are only a couple flag-setting instructions in the loop.  OOO execution will still easily get the loop-counter instructions done far ahead executing the rest of the loop, letting it start loads for future iterations, and still overlap the execution of multiple iterations.  (I didn't read the code carefully to see if there was a loop-carried dependency).

Comment: Anyway, now that P4 has been obsolete for a while, modern compilers emit `inc` and `dec` again to save a code byte or two.  You only have to avoid `inc` in cases where you can't just replace it with add.  e.g. an `adc` loop that needs to preserve `CF` from one adc to the next.  To avoid partial-flags merging slowdowns, you have to loop with lea / jecxz or something.  Or unroll a bit and still use `inc` to not clobber CF; on recent Intel that may still be cheaper.